# "Undefined variable" in view when setting $data['variable'] in constructor; works when set in function

Tags: php, codeigniter

If I set `$data['error']` in function `index()` and `echo $error` in view, it shown in my view page. However, if I set the variable in the constructor like below, and try to `echo $error` in the view page, it shows Severity:

> Notice Message: Undefined variable: error.

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller
{

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $data['error'] = 'hello';
}

function index()
{
    //$data['error'] = 'hello';

    $data['main_content'] = 'login';

    $this->load->view('inc/template', $data);
}
}
```

Comment: because $error does not exist, $data['error'] does... But that variable is local to that __construct function, how are you even trying to access it?

Comment: i see. If i want set the initial value of $data['error'] to 'hello', and i will redirect to login/index in a different function and be able to override the initial value, how do i do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to scope here is a short example:

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    /**
     * @var  array  only accessable within the scope of $this, inside Login class
     */
    private $data = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $foo = 'bar';
        $this->data = ['error' => 'hello'];
    }

    public function index()
    {
        var_dump($foo); // Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable: foo
        // it's only available in the scope of __construct()

        $this->data['main_content'] = 'login';

        // here you pass $this->data and then CI will extract the array keys
        // giving you access to the $error variable
        $this->load->view('inc/template', $this->data);
    }
}
```

This is exactly the same as with regular procedural PHP, you don't have access to variables in functions without using `global $varName`, you must pass in the variables.

I'd recommend a quick read through [the basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since you only define the $data locally to the constructor function block

if you like to have a variable accessible to any of the class function blocks

then you can create a new property of the class

```
public $data;
private $data;
```

then

on the constructor block you can use it like

```
$this->data['error'] = 'hellow';
```

and on the function index block

```
$this->data['main_content'] = 'login';
```

Answer (score 0):

`$data` is treated as different in every function of a controller

if you create a `$data` in constructor and same in index they are treated as different variable, where their scope is also local

> public function __construct() should contain:

```
 allocating resources used in entire class ex. $this->load
 check user authentication (if entire class requires it)
```

> public function index() should contain:

```
 allocating resources used only in this function
 calling views or displaying anything
```

remember **resources only in this function**

or create $data as a global variable in the class and use it as `$this->data` wherever required

Answer (score 0):

It seems as you are not understanding variable scope on this issue.

Try something like this.

```
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->data['error'] = 'hello';
    }
    function index()
    {
        //$data['error'] = 'hello';

        $data['main_content'] = 'login';
        $this->load->view('inc/template', $this->data);
    }
}

You can then also pass it to the view using the variable $this->data too.
```

Comment: `$data['main_content'] = 'login';` should be `$this->data['main_content'] = 'login';` and a variable declaration with appropriate scope in class, `public $data;`